# Usage of jar with .java files and odd behavior of the compiler

Tags: java, android, jar

I was curious about the differences between `.jar` with `.class` files and `.jar` with `.java` files. I partially got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32877987/8614565), But then what is the usefulness of `.java` files in the jar?

My guess is that the java files in the jar are like an interface that prevents compilation error, because I solved the `IllegalAccessError` thrown on runtime by replacing jar files with `.class` with jar files with `.java` specifically when using `Xposed Framework`. (Got the hint from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155340/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-ref-in-pre-verified-class-resolved-to-unexpe).)

**Also**

Thank you for your explanations and they were helpful. But I want to learn more about the differences in compiler's view, because I am wondering why my app works fine even if I only included the jar with java files, not class files (**zxing**). Also there are some cases that throws IllegalAccessException when I include the jar with class files, but not thrown when I include the jar with java files(**xposed**), even though I have to include at least one of them to make the compiler(AIDE) not complain about references, like unknown package. Why does the compiler not complain when I include only jar with java files though the compiler would not be able to resolve the actual implementation of the referred classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.jar` file is basically just a `.zip` file with another extension.

A `.jar` file with `.class` files have a *special purpose* and may have special meta-data (e.g. in `META-INF` folder).

A `.jar` file `.java` files is just a `.zip` file.

It is however common for *open-source* libraries to provide 3 `.jar` files:

- One with `.class` files, to be used by your code, both to compile and to run your code.
- One with `.java` files, to be used by your IDE, so you can drill into the library code and see it. Especially useful when stepping through the code with a debugger.
- One with javadoc files (`.html` files), to be used by your IDE, so you can read the documentation about the classes and methods in the library. You do read the documentation, right?

None of those 3 files *have* to be named `.jar`. They could be renamed `.zip` so you could easily open them in your favorite Zip utility, or they could be renamed `.foo` just because...

They *should* be named `.jar`, to clarify that they are **Java ARchives**.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to reduce number of qusetions I would have to ask, the javadoc.jar.

Comment: I understood your explanation and it was helpful. But I want to learn more about the differences in compiler's view, because I am wondering why my app works fine even if I only included the jar with java files, not class files. Also there are some cases that throws IllegalAccessException when I include the jar with class files, but not thrown when I include the  jar with java files, even though I have to include at least one of them to make the compiler(AIDE) not complain about references, like unknown package. Why does the compiler not complain when I include only jar with java files?

Comment: Though the compiler would not be able to resolve the actual implementation of the referred classes.

Comment: Or do I have to ask new question?

Answer (score 1):

Its simple - `*.java` files are sources, `*.class` files are compiled classes.

What is used on runtime by JVM?? `*.class` files. Why would you put source files inside library? IDK, usally sources are distributed as separate jar, but all in all it is done to allow you to check library code without decompilation.